# Is there academic studies or surveys on ideologies within Esperanto?

Tags: culture

I have read that there are two ideologies within the Esperanto community, regarding what people think Esperanto should be: One being Finvenkismo, and another being Rauxmismo.

My questions are:

- Are these the only ideologies?
- How many people adopt them?

Please note for the second question, while answers such as "I feel xx% of people adopt xxismo" are still appreciated, I prefer numbers based on **objective facts**: Statistics, Surveys, Journal Papers, Conference Proceedings, etc.

A definition of Rauxmismo and Finvenkismo is **not produced on purpose**, since that is a question for the researchers. I will take whatever definition they produced.

Comment: Very unclear question. What do you call "raŭmisto"? Is it even the proper term? Why do oppose "finvenkisto" and "raŭmisto"?

Comment: I don’t know if there has ever been conducted a statistical survey on this?

Comment: @Vanege Hi! I finished all your tinycards deck :) I understand this might be a sensitive subject, but I still think it is worth to try to find a way to answer, since critics often point to perceived finvenkismo. I got the term Rauxmisto from Evildea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1kKWF_8TEY

Comment: Personally I would draw the line at "would you ask someone to learn esperanto before they express an interest", but certainly people have different definitions, which is why, when I asked, "do you lean more towards", If someone says "nah i don't lean towards one more than other", that would be acceptable to me as well.

Comment: could you please add your definitions of the two terms into your question?

Comment: @eMBee that would defeat my purpose because I'm not here to prescribe what definition people should use, but to ask about how people feel about themselves.

Comment: if you use a term, then you have some definition of it. please share that. i can't respond to the question because i have never heard either terms and i can't figure out what they are supposed to mean. the video you link does contain definitions, so you could copy those definitions into the question without adding anything that you didn't already express.

Comment: @eMBee The goal of this question is not to ask personal opinions -- that would not be a good stack exchange question anyways -- but "whether there are researches done on this". Hence the question was "do we have any numbers"

Comment: @Zuoanqh If you don't define raŭmisto, you are basically asking for personal opinions on what it means. It is a term that is very rarely used, and Evildea used it projecting a meaning I think it does not deserve. It would even be better if you don't use this word, but use something more precise such as "someone who don't care about Esperanto being the second language of the world". Only then you can draw a real opposition with "finvenkisto".

Comment: @Zuoanqh any answer to the question depends on the definition of the terms. you have given definitions by pointing at the video. all i am suggesting is to make the definitions explicit in the question, so that the can be understood without watching the video.

Comment: I will no longer respond to above comment because they are not constructive to my question, and I don't believe they are in good faith in discussing my question with me.

Comment: I am disappointed that this question has been put on hold. But I guess this is stack exchange, and that's the kind of thing that happens here. Definitions, in any case, are straightforward, are in opposition (which is why the Rauma Manifesto happened to begin with), and are indeed not quite what is in the YouTube video. Finvenkismo is the notion that the point and value of Esperanto lies in its adoption as a universal language. Rauxmismo is the notion that the value of Esperanto lies in the culture it already supports. The former treat Esperanto as a political cause. (Cont)

Comment: Giorgio Silfer, the main ideologue of Rauxmismo, referred to Esperanto as a cultural diaspora, which makes it identity focused. Reformulating the question as whether people think of Esperanto as an ideology or an identity would get to the core, but the opposition had been express in those particular terms since the 1980s.

Comment: I kind of feel like the people who are commenting that raŭmismo is a rare term or don't know what it means - that they should just stay out of the conversation. If you're not familiar with the topic enough to know what this means, then you've got no business answering the question. It's a fairly common term, and defined by an entire manifesto. Don't get your info from YouTube. Read the manifesto.